# Show/prove that this is a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

**Let *A* be a matrix of size *m* by *n*. Show that *T* : R<sup>*n*</sup> → R<sup>*m*</sup> given by *T*(*v*) = *Av* for ∀*v* ∈ R<sup>*n*</sup> is a linear transformation.**

I don't even know where to begin, for proof problems. I mean, can I just stick values in, and if it works, then it's true? All I know is that a linear transformation is the mapping T of a vector space V to another W, and that it doesn't break addition and scalar multiplication. Or in math lingo: ∀*u*,*v* ∈ *V*, *T*(*u*+*v*) = *T*(*u*) + *T*(*v*). And for ∀ ∈ *α* in R, *T*(*αv*) = *αT*(*v*).

Comment: Alright, that's a good start. You would let A, v be an arbitrary matrix/vector, and probably use some axioms about matrices from an earlier lesson/chapter to prove this statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** "Or in math lingo: ∀u,v ∈ V, T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v). And for ∀ ∈ α in R, T(αv) = αT(v)."

This is exactly what you have to check, for $T$ defined as $T{\bf v} = A{\bf v}$. Compute $T({\bf u}+\alpha{\bf v})$ and see what you get.

---

**Remark:** "I mean, can I just stick values in, and if it works, then it's true?" No. You have to check, in general, for *all* ${\bf u},{\bf v}$ and $\alpha$. If you plug random values you're not checking for all of them. You can do this, at best, to convince yourself that the assertion is true. And yet, don't trust your intuition too much.

Comment: I've finished it. I just took the 2 linear transformation rules T(u+v) = T(u) + T(v), and T(cv)=cT(v), expanded/fiddled with the right side of the equations to end up with the left side, meaning that they were equal and true.